# How to install a particular version of an apt-package using ansibe

Tags: nginx, ansible

I have an ansible playbook as below, where I'm installing nginx on an ubuntu machine.

```yaml
- apt:
   name: nginx
   state: present
   update_cache: yes
```

I want to upgrade nginx to version "x". I don't want to use `state: latest`. Is there a way to specify the version which I want to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the version with `=<version>` on the name parameter.
For example:

```yaml
- apt:
   name: "nginx=1.14.0-0ubuntu1.9"
   state: present
   update_cache: yes
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#parameter-name).

Comment: I have editted the question after trying the above method.

Comment: @Legitimate_Figure_4430 what you added is a completely different question and has nothing to do with the original one. It is not even related to ansible. I suggest you revert that edit and open a new question (please search the internet before doing so, you might find something useful)

Comment: Opened a new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68468542/updating-nginx-version-via-ansible-on-centos

Comment: @Legitimate_Figure_4430 great! please consider accepting my answer if it answers the question